# Designing a wrapper around a WCF web service for using generic CRUD methods - a good solution?

Tags: generics, web-services, repository

As you all know creating a web service with generic methods is not possible. You have to design the message.

But I had the idea of creating a wrapper around WCF using Reflection.

```
public class WcfRepository<T> : IWcfRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
        public IList<T> GetList()
        {   
            Type wcfService = typeof (Service1Client);

            string entityName = typeof(T).Name;
            string methodName = String.Format("Get{0}List", entityName);

            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(wcfService, true);

            var result = (IList<T>) wcfService.InvokeMember(methodName,
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Default, null, instance, null);
            return result;
        }

        public T Save(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You would use the wrapper like this:

```
var result = new WcfRepository<Employee>().GetList();
```

Here is the cumbersome way without the wrapper:

```
var customers = myWcfService.GetCustomerList();
var teams = myWcfService.GetTeamList();
var products = myWcfService.GetProductList();
```

So what do you think about my wrapper?
What advantages and disadvantages you can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your **implementation** is that WCF proxies are not cheap.  The Reflection won't hurt you that much, but creating a new proxy for every request (and not disposing it properly, by the way) definitely will.

The main problem with your **design** is that it assumes every type of entity supports the same CRUD contract/interface.  In reality, you might have some that are read-only (bootstrap and other metadata), some that are CR-only (log or transactional data), some that are CRU-only (critical foundational data like a "store" or "account"), and some that aren't true entities at all and require additional parameters to retrieve.  In addition, you will probably need several "GetByID/GetByXYZ" type methods that vary from one type to another; rarely would a consumer truly want to list every single item contained in the database without any kind of filter or projection.

By attempting to create a generic abstraction, you are hiding critical information about what the service can actually support, and allowing consumers to make assumptions that they won't know are invalid until it's too late.  You've created a scenario that allows code to break in unexpected and even unpredictable ways.

The main problem with your **concept** is that **Web Services are intended to encapsulate business or application logic, not data sources**.  Creating a thin veneer over a DAL adds no real value to the overall solution, just another layer of indirection that clients will be forced to deal with.  Web Services are great, but they add significant development and maintenance overhead, because every schema/data update has to happen in two places instead of one.  Adding a 3rd (or 4th, or 5th) tier to an application is generally only appropriate when that tier is providing some additional *intelligence* or at least *encapsulation*.  Service architectures built entirely around data-access operations are a "bad architecture smell" as they merely re-implement the database with severely limited functionality.

For example, a service- or message-oriented request for "Orders" will likely allow the consumer to specify any or all of the customer, date range, and a slew of other domain-specific criteria - product types, quantities, total cost, payment method, and so on.  You would want to consolidate this all into a *single* Service Operation; the consumer sends a single *message* specifying in detail what he wants, and you provide it accordingly.  Of course, a similar request for "Customers" will not have any of these criteria; instead you might return results based on the sign-up date, geographic location, credit rating, etc.  Every request will be completely unique in this sense; you are providing a *service* to consumers to allow them the flexibility that a simple CRUD layer rarely provides.  You would do this in order to be able to expose it to a variety of different consumers with different needs without having to constantly change the service's *contract*.  Your proposed architecture does not lend itself well to this ultimate goal.

This may perhaps be simply my opinion and other people may have other things to say about it; all I can add is that I base these statements upon personal experience with Web Services (which I work with daily) and not necessarily conventional wisdom - although I believe that conventional wisdom agrees with me here.

Comment: "Web Services are great, but they add significant development and maintenance overhead, because every schema/data update has to happen in two places instead of one." Exactly, I encounter lots of people that don't realize this a violation of DRY.

Comment: Have to counter with "It depends." Putting a wrapper (web service) around a DAL object is useful, if it gets the data to a place that it wasn't available before (e.g., Silverlight, Flash, etc.) A smart or dynamic proxy builder takes care of the multiple updates for schema changes.

Comment: True, and I believe that was one of the main reasons why Microsoft released ADO.NET Data Services.  Still, I personally question whether you'd really want to expose such low-level functionality to a Flash or Silverlight app that probably only needs a few basic functions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread accidentally but the curious thing is that i'm working in my free time on a solution for the same problem exposed here just as a hobie because right now at work, we have about 300 services and this is growing, and there are basic operations (CRUD) that have the same structure and only change the EntityType, and there are also many custom methods, and i don't like repeating that, so i think is not a bad idea at all, but i want to take care about some of the issues explained - in my opinion - very well by Aaronaguth because now i will be thinking on how to response to those things. too.

So basically the concept is the same just one service (considering the complete solution maybe will be more but right now just one) that handles all kind of requests.

So, about the different parameters, i have a method in the service called Execute(Request request) that receive a request, this request could be a general Request object or a custom Request object like CreateRequest or DeleteRequest. The custom request has the properties that are needed for that operation, so i could create also an ApproveRequest. This request has the info about the EntityType, the operation name declared in the BusinessComponent and there are others parameters (the request acts like a property bag or dictionary), and the business components methods are defined like: Update(BusinessEntity entity), or Approve(Guid orderId, bool anotherParameterHere).

When execute is called, i process the request and extract the info that i need basically the EntityType and the OperationName, and then i map the input parameters in the request object to the expected parameters of the method i get this done using reflection too... and in the BaseBusinessComponent i can create an strongly type object of the BusinessEntity lets say Customer, this customer inherits from BusinessEntity.

Another important thing is the response that is handled in the same way of the request if the request has a corresponding response class (just replace Request by Response) then i create an object of this request and add the values returned by the method in the business component so i could return a property bag and copy all the properties to the Response or if it's not a property bag i assign the value (if the method is not void) to a general property "Result", and this result maybe in my CustomResponse i could override it and read the value and assign each individual property that is known in the CustomResponse class (but i haven't done this yet).

This is the example of the code that i can write right now is something very basically:

```
            AppService service = new AppService();

            //Create an order
            BusinessEntity order = new BusinessEntity("Order");
            order["OrderId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            order["CustomerName"] = "Greivin Britton";

            CreateRequest request = new CreateRequest();
            request.Entity = order;

            CreateResponse response = (CreateResponse)service.Execute(request);

            //Create a customer
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.FirstName = "Greivin";
            customer.LastName = "Britton";

            Request request2 = new Request();
            request2.MessageName = "Create";
            request.Entity = customer;

            Response response2 = service.Execute(request2);
```

For retrieving data using different filters maybe i will have to create an ExpressionBuilder class or something like that...